# AJAX with JSONP datatype receives 404 on no result

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Im having some trouble with an AJAX response that i dont know how to handle.

You see im sending a request to a site using GET with AJAX and dataType jsonp. Its supposed to return some data based on a number. If no data is found on the number sent it returns a 404. I just dont know how i can handle that when im using jsonp.

```
jQuery.ajax
        ({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=" + vat + "&country=" + country,
                success: function (b)
                {
                    console.log(b);
                    $('input:text[name=company_name]').val(b['name']);
                    $('input:text[name=zip]').val(b['zipcode']);
                    $('input:text[name=city]').val(b['city']);
                    $('input:text[name=phone]').val(b['phone']);                                                 
                }                   
        });
```

I've tried with `error: function() {}` after the success function, but the error function is never called.

How can i somehow let AJAX see that i receive a 404 message and act on it?

The number input is from the user, and if the user enters a wrong number i would like them to get a error message.

Comment: I tried my own petitions on that api and all are returned with an error 500, not found....

Comment: jquery 1.8+ ajax have not error but fail handler

Answer (score 0):

may help http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

section:

**Example**: Send an id as data to the server, save some data to the server, and notify the user once it's complete. If the request fails, alert the user.

you can handle `jqXHR` or `status` via `request.fail` function.